# Setting foreignkey in formsets

Tags: django

I am getting this error

> **reports_student.classroom_id may not be NULL**

Here is my view. What am I doing wrong here? I think the problem is caused by setting the foreign keys. Classroom belongs to user... students belong to classroom...

```
def build_classroom(request):
    print "building classroom"
    # Empty formset forms should be required
    class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for form in self.forms:
                form.empty_permitted = False
    StudentFormSet = formset_factory(StudentForm, max_num=100, formset=RequiredFormSet)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

        classroom_form = ClassroomForm(request.POST)
        student_formset = StudentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if classroom_form.is_valid() and student_formset.is_valid():
            classroom = classroom_form.save(commit=False)
            classroom.user = request.user
            for form in student_formset.forms:
                student = form.save(commit=False)
                student.classroom = classroom
                student.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # Redirect to a 'success' page
    else:
        classroom_form = ClassroomForm()
        student_formset = StudentFormSet()

    # For CSRF protection
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ 
    c = {'classroom_form': classroom_form,
         'student_formset': student_formset,
        }
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('reports/build_classroom.html', c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
classroom = classroom_form.save(commit=False)
```

Since you have used `commit=False` on the classroom form, `classroom` likely doesn't have an ID value that can be assigned to `student`.

Save the classroom instance first (omit the `commit=False`).

```
    if classroom_form.is_valid() and student_formset.is_valid():
        classroom = classroom_form.save(commit=False) # So you can add FK
        classroom.user = request.user # exclude("user",) in forms.py so it validates
        classroom.save() # put it in the database for student
        for form in student_formset.forms:
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            student.classroom = classroom # classroom is in the database
            student.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did put the whole chunk of code... See edited post

Comment: How do I get around `commit=False` when I am setting `classroom.user`

Comment: Without it I get, `reports_classroom.user_id may not be NULL`

Comment: Then you must supply `user_id` to classroom before it's saved. You can't get around needing a saved classroom instance to save a student.

Comment: How do I do this? I've updated the post again with more code.

Comment: You must save classroom. Your classroom __must have an id__ before you can apply it to a student and thus resolve the condition that a student must have a classroom.

Comment: But when I do that I can't do this: classroom.user = request.user

Comment: Oh!  I needed to do this: classroom = classroom_form.save(commit=False)
            classroom.user = request.user
            classroom.save()